# My XBOX One doesn't respond to voice commands

Tags: xbox-one

I've just got a XBOX One, and it doesn't seem to respond to voice commands, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try to? Do you have a Kinect? Is it enabled in the settings?

Comment: It won't do anything different.I do not have a kinect.

Comment: Have you ever had a look at your console's [instruction manual](http://support-origin.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/voice-commands)? `With Kinect voice recognition, you can control and interact with your Xbox One console by using voice commands.` Obviously you need a Kinect to use "***Kinect*** voice recognition".

Answer (score 9):

You need a Kinect in order to use Voice Control feature of Xbox One.